# Noweb references in sh blocks breaks the syntax highlighting

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, bash, noweb

I use noweb references inside sh code blocks, for example:

```
#+begin_src sh
  echo "test"
  <<some-ref>>
  echo "test"
#+end_src
```

But this causes syntax highlighting to be broken because `<<` gets interpreted as *here document* by the sh syntax highlighter and rest of the document (line 3 for the example above) becomes non-highlighted.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You could try the code from https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63306/emphasize-text-snippets-in-source-blocks and set `(setq org-babel-default-header-args (cons '(:emph . "'((\"<<\" \">>\" 'hi-red-b))") (assq-delete-all :emph org-babel-default-header-args)))` file-locally in the org files where you need it or even in your init file if you really want that. Save the code in some file within your `load-path`, e.g., `org+-emph.el` and byte-compile it. Add `(require 'org+-emph)` to your init file.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? If not, what was the problem?

Comment: @Tobias Thanks for the suggestion! Sorry for not being able to get back earlier. I tried your solution but it completely broke the syntax highlighting in the src blocks. It seems to be working (although with some little problems)  if I write the src block manually or paste it from somewhere else, but right after editing it with `C-c '` the colors gets mixed up. OK, right now I realized the problem is the 2-space indentation that org automatically applies after doing `C-c '`, your package does not account for that I guess.

Comment: Please use [package `org-src-emph`](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/org-src-emph/). See the installation guide and the usage examples there.
The code has some fix that hopefully makes editing with `C-c '` fully functional. It is clear that the Noweb references may interfere with the source code in the special edit buffer. I had to rename the package to comply with the guidelines of Melpa. If the package is stable enough we could propose it for Melpa. Please test.

Comment: @Tobias although I am not the author of this question, I had the same problem and I tried your package. It solved the problem! Thanks for your work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the delimiters babel use for noweb references, by setting `org-babel-noweb-wrap-start` and `org-babel-noweb-wrap-start`.

For instance, in org mode document where I dabble in bash, I insert at the bottom of the file:

```
* COMMENT Local Variables
# Local Variables:
# org-babel-noweb-wrap-start: "«"
# org-babel-noweb-wrap-end: "»"
# End:
```

The syntax to refer to noweb now is:

```
#+begin_src sh :noweb yes
«ze_bloc_to_include»
#+end_src
```

I like to use `«` and `»` characters, because they are very similar to `<<` and `>>`, but you can choose other combination.

The drawback of this solution : it changes for the whole buffer, not only a single block. Otherwise, pretty great all around.

Answer (score 4):

I liked @Dreammm's idea of using the `«` and `»` characters but didn't like having to declare file local variables.

I also did not want to always use `«` and `»`.

I just overwrote the `org-babel-noweb-wrap` function so now I can use either `<<` and `>>` or `«` and `»`.

```lisp
(defun org-babel-noweb-wrap (&optional regexp)
  "Return regexp matching a Noweb reference.

Match any reference, or only those matching REGEXP, if non-nil.

When matching, reference is stored in match group 1."
  (rx-to-string
   `(and (or "<<" "«")
           (group
            (not (or " " "\t" "\n"))
            (? (*? any) (not (or " " "\t" "\n"))))
           (or ">>" "»"))))
```